# Is the probability density function unique?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Is the [probability density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) (pdf) unique?

For example, I've seen the pdf of the uniform distribution written in two different versions, one with strict inequality and the other is not strict. From the definition, pdf is a function $f$ such that $P(X\in B)=\int_B f$. So it seems that the value of $x$ at one particular point doesn't really matter. Am I correct?

Comment: Depends. If your pdf has a point mass somewhere, it would matter. For example, a mixture of half a uniform distribution, and a $0.5$ point mass at $x$, then the CDF would have a "jump" at $x$.

Answer (score 16):

Indeed. If two (measurable) functions coincide except on a set of measure zero, then each one is as legitimate as the other to be the density of the probability distribution of a given random variable.

For example, consider the Borel function $f$ defined on $\mathbb R$ by $f(x)=1$ for every irrational $x$ in $(0,1)$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. For every random variable $X$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and every Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb R$, $\mathrm P(X\in B)=\int\limits_Bf(x)\mathrm dx$. Since this is how the density of the probability distribution of $X$ is defined, the function $f$ is indeed a density for the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, as suitable as the functions $\mathbf 1_{[0,1]}$ or $\mathbf 1_{(0,1)}$ (of course, the latter are more common choices).